# Angular Material vertical percentage space

Tags: angular-material

How can I make one div to take certain percent of parent space verically?See the code below:

```
<div layout="column">
  <div id="div1" flex="70%"></div>
  <div id="div2" flex="30%"></div>
</div>
```

I want to make div1 70% height and div2 30% height of parent div. But it does not work. Div 1 and div 2 collapsed. But if the parent layout is row, it works fine---div1 takes 70% percent space horizontally.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to make the following modifications:

1. Specify a "height" to your outside div.  This could be a percentage or pixels.
2. Do not use the % sign with the flex attribute

See this codepen: http://codepen.io/sebastiengiroux/pen/jPovxG

```
<div layout="column" style="height: 100%;">
  <div id="div1" flex="70" style="background-color:red;"></div>
  <div id="div2" flex="30" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, 100% height works but the inner divs are one line each

Answer (score -1):

If you look into Layout docs https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction
there is this statement that I think is relevant to your problem.

> The flex attribute value is restricted to 33, 66, and multiples of five.
>
> For example: flex="5", flex="20", flex="33", flex="50", flex="66", flex="75", ....

So I guess if you use allowed values, you can achieve results that you need. For example using **66** and **33**.

Comment: if you had read correctly, you might have noticed that it says "... 33, 66 and multiples of five."! Since 70 and 30 are multiples of five this was absolutely not the problem.